# Is there any way to convert JSON query to Elasticsearch Nest search query?

Tags: c#, json, elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to convert JSON query to elasticsearch query but I am failed. 
my query is of grouping data (aggregation).

```
{
"aggs":{
   "ResultCount":{
    "terms":{
              "field":"type"
            },
    "aggs":{
      "hits":{
        "top_hits":{
                "_source":{
                  "include":[
                                "year",
                                "type"
                            ]
                          }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code that i tried:

```
var result = Client.Search<ModelClass>(s => s
            .Index("myIdx")
            .Type("myType")
            .Aggregations(a => a
                .Terms("ResultCount", t => t
                    .Field(p => p.year)
                )
            )
        );
```

Help if possible. Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should look like this

```
client.Search<ModelClass>(s => s
    .Index("myIndex")
    .Type("myType")
    .Aggregations(a => a
        .Terms("ResultCount", t => t.Field(p => p.Type)
            .Aggregations(a1 => a1
                .TopHits("myHits", h => h
                    .Source(d => d
                        .Includes(fd => fd
                            .Fields(
                                f1 => f1.Type, 
                                f2 => f2.Year
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

`hits` is reserved keyword, so I used `myHits` instead of it.
Also, in your json query you have `include`, I think it should be `includes`

**Edit:** Items of the `result.Aggs.Terms("ResultCount").Buckets.ToList()` will have the following structure

```
{
    "key": 2000,
    "doc_count": 1,
    "myHits": {
      "hits": {
         "total": 1,
         "max_score": 1,
         "hits": [
            {
               "_index": "myIndex",
               "_type": "myType",
               "_id": "AVupJZbRLWQhMqJPXgXa",
               "_score": 1,
               "_source": {
                  "year": 2000,
                  "type": "some type"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
}
```

Comment: First of all Thank you  so much for your @Ruben . still not getting desire output. i have several query how can i get this two fields in each bucket (group) of aggregation. ?

Comment: You want to have 2 buckets, one for each property. In the result you want to see one bucket for `type` property and another for `year`, just with the grouped counts of the property. Am I right?

Comment: yes
`var response = result.Aggs.Terms("ResultCount").Buckets.ToList();`
but here i am not getting list of bucket which contain type and year. which is required actually.

Comment: I added the structure of the bucket to the answer. Is it ok for you?

Comment: yes exactly! I have got that JSON structure by using that response but i want to get year and type for specific bucket. how do i get it ? @RubenVardanyan

Comment: You can define separate aggregations for each field to get them grouped within separate buckets. @DivyeshGausvami

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142722/discussion-between-divyesh-gausvami-and-ruben-vardanyan).